# Simpler way of computing the first homology group of $\Delta^4$ (without the interior)?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Here's my attempt. The first part (computing $Z_1$) feels like it's far too complicated. First of all - is my work correct? And second, is there a simpler way of doing this?

Let's label the $0$-simplices $(v_1,...,v_5)$, $1$-simplices $(e_1,...,e_{10})$. Now, we are looking for the following chain complex:
$$C_2\overset{\partial_2}\to C_1\overset{\partial_1}\to C_0.$$
Here, 
$$C_0=\mathbb{Z} \langle v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4,v_5 \rangle $$
$$C_1=\mathbb{Z} \langle v_1v_2 \rangle \oplus\mathbb{Z} \langle v_1v_3 \rangle \oplus\mathbb{Z} \langle v_1v_4 \rangle \oplus\mathbb{Z} \langle v_1v_5 \rangle \oplus\mathbb{Z} \langle v_2v_3 \rangle \\ \oplus\mathbb{Z} \langle v_2v_4 \rangle \oplus\mathbb{Z} \langle v_2v_5 \rangle \oplus\mathbb{Z} \langle v_3v_4 \rangle \oplus\mathbb{Z} \langle v_3v_5 \rangle \oplus\mathbb{Z} \langle v_4v_5 \rangle $$ 
$$C_2=\mathbb{Z} \langle v_1v_2v_3 \rangle \oplus\mathbb{Z} \langle v_1v_2v_4 \rangle \oplus\mathbb{Z} \langle v_1v_2v_5 \rangle \oplus\mathbb{Z} \langle v_1v_3v_4 \rangle \oplus\mathbb{Z} \langle v_1v_3v_5 \rangle \\ \oplus\mathbb{Z} \langle v_1v_4v_5 \rangle \oplus\mathbb{Z} \langle v_2v_3v_4 \rangle \oplus\mathbb{Z} \langle v_2v_3v_5 \rangle \oplus\mathbb{Z} \langle v_2v_4v_5 \rangle \oplus\mathbb{Z} \langle v_3v_4v_5 \rangle $$
$\partial_1$ does the following maps:
$$e_1 \mapsto v_2-v_1$$
$$e_2 \mapsto v_3-v_1$$
$$e_3 \mapsto v_4-v_1$$
$$e_4 \mapsto v_5-v_1$$
$$e_5 \mapsto v_3-v_2$$
$$e_6 \mapsto v_4-v_2$$
$$e_7 \mapsto v_5-v_2$$
$$e_8 \mapsto v_4-v_3$$
$$e_9 \mapsto v_5-v_3$$
$$e_{10} \mapsto v_5-v_4$$
Now, to compute $H_1$ we need to find $Z_1=\ker(\partial_1)$. Therefore, we need to find the linear combinations of $\partial_1(e_1),...,\partial_1(e_{10})$ such that
$$\partial_1\Big( w_1(e_1)+....+w_{10}(e_{10})\Big) =0$$
$$w_1(v_2-v_1)+...+w_{10}(v_5-v_4)=0.$$
We can re-write this as
$$v_1(-w_1-w_2-w_3-w_4)+...+v_5(w_4+w_7+w_9+w_{10})=0$$
which is equivalent to setting the following matrix to zero (columns represent the $w_i$s, rows represent the $v_i$s):

$$\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & 0 & 0 &0  &0  &  0&0 \\ 
 1& 0 &0  &0  & -1 &-1  &-1  &0  &0  &0 \\ 
 0& 1 & 0 &0  &1  &0  &0  &-1  &-1  &0 \\ 
 0&  0&1  &0  &0  &1  & 0 &1  &0  &-1 \\ 
 0&0  &  0&1  & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &1  &1 
\end{pmatrix}$$
Putting it into row echelon form:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0  & 0  &  0 & 0 \\ 
 0& 1 &1  &1  & 1 &1  &1  &0  &0  &0 \\ 
 0& 0 & 1 &1  &0  &1 &1 &1  &1  &0 \\ 
 0&  0& 0 &1  &0  &0  & 1 &0  &1  &1 \\ 
 0&0  &  0&0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0  &0 
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & -1 & -1  & 0  &  0 & 0 \\ 
 0& 1 & 0  &0  & 1 &0  &0  &-1  &-1  &0 \\ 
 0& 0 & 1 &0  &0  &1 &0 &1  &0  &-1 \\ 
 0&  0& 0 &1  &0  &0  & 1 &0  &1  &1 \\ 
 0&0  &  0&0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0  &0 
\end{pmatrix}$$
Let's call the $5^{th}$th column $r_1$, the $6^{th}$ one $r_2$, the $7^{th}$ one $r_3$, the $8^{th}$ one $r_4$, the $9^{th}$ one $r_5$, the $10^{th}$ one $r_6$. So now
$$r_1\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
-1 \\
0 \\
0 \\
1 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
 0
 \end{pmatrix}+
r_2\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
-1 \\
0 \\
0  \\
1 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0 \end{pmatrix}+
r_3\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
 0\\
0 \\
-1 \\
0  \\
0 \\
1 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0 \end{pmatrix}+
r_4\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
1 \\
-1 \\
0 \\
0  \\
0 \\
0 \\
1 \\
0 \\
0 \end{pmatrix}+
r_5\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
1 \\
0 \\
 -1\\
0  \\
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
1 \\
0 \end{pmatrix}+
r_6\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
1 \\
 -1\\
0  \\
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
1 \end{pmatrix}=
 \begin{pmatrix}
w_1 \\
w_2 \\
w_3 \\
 w_4\\
 w_5 \\
 w_6 \\
 w_7 \\
 w_8 \\
 w_9 \\
 w_{10}
 \end{pmatrix}$$
Solutions: multiples of cycles:
$$w_1-w_2+w_5$$
$$w_1-w_3+w_6$$
$$w_1-w_4+w_7$$
$$w_2-w_3+w_8$$
$$w_2-w_4+w_9$$
$$w_3-w_4+w_{10},$$
where we associate each $w_i$ with the corresponding edge $e_i$.
So $Z_1=\mathbb{Z}^6$.
Now we need to find $B_1$, which is the image of $\partial_2$. The boundaries of the $2$-simplices can all be written as multiples of the cycles listed above. Hence, $B_1=Z_1$ and their quotient must be the trivial group $0$.

Comment: Can you use cellular homology?

Comment: Haven't studied that yet, I'm afraid

Comment: I edited my answer. The problem leads to the calculation of the homology of a sphere. I calculate it in my answer by using Mayer-Vietoris. Another way is described in Hatcher's book on p. 107, Example 2.2 and 2.5 and on p. 114, Corollary 2.14.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your title, I am going to assume that your intention is to compute the homology of $\Delta^4 - \text{interior}(\Delta^4)$, although you did not mention that again in the text of the question.

One thing about homology is, if you find yourself doing torturous computations, especially with such a fundamental example, probably there is an easier way.

$\Delta^4$, being contractible, has trivial homology in all dimensions except in dimension $0$ where its homology is $\mathbb{Z}$ since it is connected.

$\Delta^4 - \text{interior}(\Delta^4)$ is equal to the 3-skeleton of $\Delta^4$. So, the chain complexes for $\Delta^4$ and for $\Delta^4 - \text{interior}(\Delta^4)$ are identical in dimensions $0$ through $3$, from which it follows that their homologies are isomorphic in dimensions $0$ $1$, and $2$. Thus, the homologies of $\Delta^4 - \text{interior}(\Delta^4)$ are $\mathbb{Z}$ in dimension $0$ and trivial in dimensions $1$ and $2$.

Also, the homologies of $\Delta^4 - \text{interior}(\Delta^4)$ are all zero from dimension $4$ and up, it being 3-dimensional.

That leaves dimension $3$. Each 3-simplex in $\Delta^4$ has ordered vertex set obtained from the list $(v_0,v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4)$ by removing one vertex $v_i$; give it a coefficient $+1$ if $i$ is even, $-1$ if $i$ is odd. This defines a $3$-cycle, as one can check. Furthermore, every $3$-cycle is a scalar multiple of this one, because every $2$-simplex is on the boundary of exactly two $3$-simplices, and so changing the coefficient on one 3-simplex by adding the integer $k$ forces the exact same change on each adjacent $3$-simplex by also adding $k$. Finally, since there are no 4-simplices in $\Delta^4 - \text{interior}(\Delta^4)$ its group of 3-cycles is isomorphic to its 3-dimensional homology.
Thus, 
$$H_3(\Delta^4 - \text{interior}(\Delta^4)) = \mathbb{Z}
$$

Answer (score 2):

The following answer is not the calculation of the homology of $\Delta^4\setminus int ( \Delta^4)$, but of $\Delta^4$. The correct answer can be found under the title "edit".

You can find in Hatcher (p. 111) something like the following statement:

**Corollary:** If $X$ and $Y$, two topological spaces, are homotopic equivalent, then $H_n(X)\cong H_n(Y)$.

Now you have to know this

**Lemma:** Any convex subset $X\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ satisfies $H_n(X,\mathbb{Z})=\begin{cases} \mathbb{Z}\mbox{ for } n=0,\\ 0 \mbox{ else.}\end{cases}$

**Proof:** Choose a point $p\in X$ and set $G\colon X\times I\to X,$ $(x,t)\mapsto tp+(1-t)x$.

$G$ is an homotopy from $G|_{X\times\{0\}}=id_X$ to $G|_{X\times\{1\}}=const_{p}$ and $G|_{\{p\}\times I}=id$, hence it is a deformation retraction. $\square$

**Remark:**

1.) The $const_p$ maps any element to $p$.

2.) Obviously $H_n(pt.,\mathbb{Z})=\begin{cases} \mathbb{Z}\mbox{ for } n=0,\\ 0 \mbox{ else.}\end{cases}$

3.) If $A\subseteq X$ is a deformation retract, then $A\simeq X$ are homotopic equivalent.

**Another strategy:**

Any standard $n$-simplex is homeomorphic to the $n$-ball. Then calculate the homology group of the $n$-ball.

***Edit***

Sorry for this late correction! The OP wanted to calculate $\Delta^4\setminus int (\Delta^4) $. Here's an approach. I will show a more general case:

The **standard $ q $-simplex** is defined as
$$\Delta^q=\{(t_0,..., t_q)|\sum_{i=0}^qt_i=1, t_i\in I\} $$
Now
$$\{(t_0,..., t_q)|\sum_{i=0}^qt_i=1, t_i\in I\mbox { and at least one }t_i=0 \}=\partial\Delta^q=\bar {\Delta^q}\setminus int (\Delta^q)=\Delta^q\setminus int (\Delta^q),$$
because $\Delta^q $ is closed.

$\partial \Delta^q $ is homeomorphic to $ \mathbb{S}^{q-1} $ and homeomorphic spaces have isomorphic homology groups.

The problem now is just the calculation of the **homology of the sphere $\mathbb {S}^n $.**

The calculation can be done for example with Mayer-Vietoris:

Choose $ U=\mathbb {S}^n\setminus N $ and $ V=\mathbb {S}^n\setminus S $, where $ N$ and $ S $ are the north and south pole. $ U $ and $ V $ are both homeomorphic to $\mathbb {R}^n $ by stereographic projection, which has obviously the homology group of a point (deformation retraction). The intersection $ U\cap V $ is homotopy equivalent to $ \mathbb {S}^{n-1} $ (deformation retraction).

We have the following exact sequence for $ p> 0$:

$$\underbrace {H_{p+1}(U)\oplus H_{p+1}(V)}_{=0}\longrightarrow H_{p+1}(\mathbb {S}^n)\overset {\sim}{\longrightarrow} \underbrace {H_{p}(U\cap V)}_{=H_p (\mathbb {S}^{n-1})}\longrightarrow \underbrace {H_p (U)\oplus H_p (V)}_{=0} $$
Because of exactness the middle map is a homomorphism between $ H_{p+1}(\mathbb{S}^n)\cong H_p (\mathbb {S}^{n-1}) $. Since $ H_0$ "counts" path-connected components, $ H_0 (\mathbb {S}^0)=\mathbb {Z}^2$ and $ H_0 (\mathbb {S}^n)=\mathbb {Z} $ for $ n> 0$.

Now for $ n=1$ the map $\mathbb {Z}\oplus \mathbb {Z}=H_0 (\mathbb {S}^0)\longrightarrow H_0 (\mathbb {R})\oplus H_0 (\mathbb {R})=\mathbb {Z}\oplus \mathbb {Z}$ is given by $(x, y)\mapsto (x+y, x+y) $.

By exactness we deduce $ H_p (\mathbb {S}^1)=\begin {cases}\mathbb {Z}, p=0,1\\0, \mbox { else}\end {cases} $.

By the homeomorphism before we can deduce inductively $ H_p (\mathbb {S}^n)=\begin {cases}\mathbb {Z}, p=0,n\\0, \mbox { else}\end {cases} $ for $ n\in \mathbb {N} $.

All in all $$ H_p (\Delta^q\setminus int (\Delta^q))=H_p (\mathbb {S}^{q-1})=\begin {cases} \mathbb {Z}, p=0, q-1\\0, \mbox { else}\end {cases}. $$

Comment: Note that the OP want to calculate the homology of the boundary of $\Delta^4$.

Comment: Thank you @John for your comment. I edited my answer now.  Sorry for this late reaction.